# solr / lucene: Query closest date

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to do a query in solr that returns the document closest to a given timestamp. Let's say these are my documents:

```
[{
  myDateField_dt: "2012-12-01T18:37:35.282Z"
},
{
  myDateField_dt: "2012-12-01T18:37:38.282Z"
},
{
  myDateField_dt: "2012-12-01T18:37:40.282Z"
}]
```

and this is my search date: `2012-12-01T18:37:36.282Z`

then the query should return the first date from my example docs because it's closest to my search date. How would I do this with solr / lucene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use [function queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries) to do some date math, and sort the query by the formula you build. One possible (untested) candidate:

```
&sort=ms(2012-12-01T18:37:36.282Z, myDateField_dt) asc
```

Specially useful would be ms(), if() etc functions. Check the date math [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates)

Beware to handle missing values in the date field too.

Comment: had to combine it with `abs()` because else it would return the biggest *negative* difference first. so it becomes: `abs(ms("2012-12-01T18:37:30.281Z", myDateField_dt)) asc`